# Weird gsub function

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
def word_sizes(sentence)
  sizes = Hash.new(0)
  sentence.split(' ').each do |word|
   p "#{word} => #{word.gsub(/^[a-z]/i, '')}"
  end
end

word_sizes("Four score and seven.")
```

The results I'm expecting is that the `gsub` function deletes all the non-alphabetical characters in each word. However, my output looks like this:

```
"Four => our"
"score => core"
"and => nd"
"seven. => even."
```

It seems like `gsub` only takes out the first character of each word. This is so confusing. Any ideas why?

Comment: If first splitting on word boundaries, is the `^` anchor even necessary?

Comment: @RubyG : You usage of `^` means that the pattern has to match the start of the scipt.

Comment: @user1934428: No, `^` means "start-of-line", not "start-of-script" (whatever that means). Are you thinking of `\A` which means "start-of-string"?

Comment: I wanted to say "start of string" (it was a typo). You are also right that start-of-line is correct. I'm too sloppy with this, because I rarely grep accross line boundaries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work,

```
word.gsub(/[^a-z]/i, '')
```

you just got the `^` (caret) syntax in wrong place

Comment: If you use `/[^[:word:]]/` (or `/[^[:alpha:]]/` to exclude digits and underscores) it will even work with accented letters. I'd also use `scan(/[[:word:]]+/)` to get a list of words instead of splitting on space and removing non-word characters manually.

Comment: That's helpful. Thanks a bunch!